# Keeping javascript from endlessly appending dom

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a javascript that adjusts the dom depending on the JSON response it receives for each field. an example is:

```
    if (data.errors.firstName) {
        document.getElementById("firstName-group").classList.add("has-error");
        let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
        helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
        helpBlock.innerHTML = data.errors.firstName;
        document.getElementById("firstName-group").append(helpBlock);
    }
```

The problem here is that this will result in the dom being repeatedly appending like so:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzqUg.png)

so how do I avoid this issue when appending the dom? should this clear out any appended messages already? or how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can can check if the #firstName-group element has already the .help-block div under it, and only append if it doesn't.

Here is an example:

```
if (data.errors.firstName && !document.querySelector('#firstName-group .help-block')) {
    document.getElementById("firstName-group").classList.add("has-error");
    let helpBlock = document.createElement('div');
    helpBlock.classList.add('help-block');
    helpBlock.innerHTML = data.errors.firstName;
    document.getElementById("firstName-group").append(helpBlock);
}
```